# using the default icons in vscode as guttericons

Tags: icons, vscode-extensions, text-decorations

I'm writing a extension for my own script language and want to add gutter icons using text decorations with vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType(). I got the code working for svg images that I added to my extension folder.

This works:

`gutterIconPath: context.asAbsolutePath('media/circle-outline.svg')`

But I wanted to make use of the in-build vscode.ThemeIcon() like:

`gutterIconPath: new vscode.ThemeIcon('circle-outline')`

But this doesn't work.
Does someone know how to get it work?

I saw people make it work in another context like treeview where you can do something like

`this.iconPath = new vscode.ThemeIcon("folder");`

and it worked for those people.
ChatGPT suggested it would work too. (I know it's not a reliable source, but it made sense to me)